# After upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04 i have swap problem?

Tags: swap

after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04 and running sudo apt autoremove and I restart my computer now it won't start it shows me

**activation swap Swap partition <27.462104> cdc - ether 2-1,1:1.0 enx00a0c6000000: kevent 12 may have been dropped**

now i can't even access to my computer, can you help me guys **i'm stuck**

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **/etc/fstab** file for swap partition.

You need to start Ubuntu from CD or USB, then select the option "try ubuntu",
**run GParted**.

If required delete the old swap partition and create a new swap partition.

`/etc/fstab` should have a line similar to this

```
UUID=some-unique-id-for-the-partition swap swap defaults 0 0
```

to get the unique id run `blkid` in terminal